# Django Rest Framework communicating with mobile app instances

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to build a REST Service which exchanges JSON messages with instances of a mobile app for registering patron traffic in physical locations of (public and academic) libraries.

I plan on using Django Rest Framework, and using Django and DRF for the first time, have some questions (rather, recommendation requests). I have read the tutorials and followed some of them, and it looks very promising indeed.

1. As I am quite confident with Object oriented coding in Python, I will be using class based views. Any reason not to?
2. The intended usage of the system will include many different libraries with their own ids, users and properties. The data model behind is thus fairly complex, and implemented with MySQL. I feel I will have better control on the data exchange, updates inserts and selects, with custom SQL queries, and would like the DRF to handle mostly authentication and the routing of messages to and from the instances of the mobile app. Is this a misconception on my part, and would it be better to let DRF handle all database-involved aspects?
3. Given that I follow the custom SQL approach:
   As (authenticated) user IDs are interwoven with the rest of the activities (e.g. we would like to know which of the authenticated users stands behind a certain registration of activity), it would seem "simple" to use a single database for both the business model itself and the DRF-controlled aspects. Is it recommended ? Are there any aspects that need to be considered here?
4. I have not found similar projects to be learning from. Anybody knows a similar project?

I know it is not very concrete, but hope to elevate my understanding a bit while endeavoring on the task.

Michael

Comment: Django is a bit like Apple products. If all of your devices are Apple, then it works quite well. But if some of your devices are Apple and some are PC and some are something else, it becomes a nightmare to get everything to work together. DRF works really well when you need a bunch of endpoints that map cleanly to your Django models. If they do not, and if you are using lots of custom queries, you will spend most of your time fighting against DRF.

Comment: Thanks, Neil! I have so far succeeded in implementing all my models and views without a single custom SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to keep this as unopinionated as possible. Mostly reffering from Django's and DRF's [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) to make sure.

1. Class based views have some implicit code flows, need method overrides at some places. But since you are quite comfortable with Class based views, it is far more superior in the following ways: cleaner code, much more DRY compliant than function based, easier to extend, keeps your code base more maintainable as it grows.
2. Django's ORM is pretty powerful and if used correctly it can provide a vareity of capabilities.
3. Unless your authentication system is very complex and needs to scale independently, having everything in the same DB makes sense. The chatter reduces and you will be able to utilise powerful Django and DRF's features.